# What is meant by having negligible heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics

**place of application.**

It is generally given for insulators in questions. But why?

Comment: Is the other way around, insulators have a large heat capacity.

Answer (score 1):

If we make the heat capacity go to zero, the system has no capacity to absorb heat. This does not make the material an insulator, though. An insulator has zero *thermal conductivity*, which is a different property.

Let's examine thermal capacity first. Suppose we have a tank with mass $m_T$ and heat capacity $C_{P,T}$ than contains mass $m_F$ of a fluid with heat capacity $C_{P,F}$. Initially both the tank and the contents are at temperature $T_q$. If we add and amount of heat $Q$ this will go to heat up both the fluid and the tank:
$$
   Q = m_T C_{P,T}(T_2-T_1) + m_F C_{P,F}(T_2-T_1)
$$
If we take the heat capacity of the tank to be 0 this becomes
$$
   Q = m_F C_{P,F}(T_2-T_1)
$$
The assumption allows us to ignore the effect of the tank in order to concentrate the focus of the calculation on the fluid.

Now to heat conductivity: if on the outside of the tank the temperature is $T_0$, heat will be transferred from the tank to the surroundings (assuming $T_0<T_2$), first via conduction through the wall of the tank and then by convection. The rate of this transfer is proportional to the difference between the two sides of the tank wall, $T_2$ on the inside and $T_1$ on the inside:
$$
   \dot q = \frac{k A}{L} (T_2-T_0)
$$
$k$ is the thermal conductivity, $A$ is the area of the wall and $L$ is its thickness. A thermal insulator has zero thermal conductivity ($k=0$), which means it can maintain a temperature difference without conducting any heat. This assumption allows us to assume that the temperature in the tank can be maintained indefinitely.

Comment: "If we make the heat capacity go to zero, no heat is stored in the material".  Heat is never stored in a material. That's internal energy.

Comment: Very true -- edited to read: the system has no capacity to absorb energy added in the form of heat.

Answer (score 0):

They are trying to get you to ignore the heat absorbed by the insulators. If the surface of the insulators have negligible heat capacity, then they would quickly change its temperature to equal whatever is in contact with them, with negligible transfer of heat energy for this equilibration.